# Does the current nginx Docker image no longer provide integration with ngx_http_auth_basic_module?

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm sure I've set up all the required configurations for basic auth according to the documentation, but even after entering the correct username and password in the browser, the reverse proxy URL still shows a 401 error.

I executed the following command within the Docker container to see if nginx includes the ngx_http_auth_basic_module module:

```
nginx -V 2>&1 | grep -o 'http_auth_basic_module'
```

The output of this command is empty.
So I would like to ask, does the current nginx Docker image no longer integrate this module? What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Not programming or development, but: http_auth_basic is built by default; [a config option is used (and shown by -V) only to _remove_ it](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/auto/options#L267) (--without-http_auth_basic_module). Also, if it _was_ omitted, nginx would have given an error when you tried to use its config directives.